# How to run a query from a string in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run a query which is saved in a string, for example: `str='select 753 as number'`

I tried exec sql but am getting this error:

> EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str

Also I am using it in a postgresql function. SO I have a dynamic query in a string. How can I run query in a string which can be returned as cursor. Something like this:

```
    prepare strg as 'select 7777 as number';
    open fcur for execute strg;
```

can it be done?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Which environment?

Comment: What programming language are you using? In PL/pgSQL you only use `execute`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute a string which returns rows with "**EXECUTE IMMEDIATE string**":

> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE immediately prepares and executes a dynamically specified SQL statement, without retrieving result rows. ([Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-execute-immediate.html))

You can however execute a command that a variable hosts:

```
str='Delete * from table01'
EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :str;
```

However you can use Prepare and Execute:

```
prepare str as select 753 as number;
execute str;
```

To select into a cursor, first **open cursor** and then **select data into it**.

Comment: In prepare str command I cannot prepare sql from string. Also, Can you please tell me How can I return this in function as cursor. I updated my question.